# Trying to exclude an elements in an array if it overlaps with another array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, random

I am writing code that pseudorandomises positions from an array:

```
centre_pos = ['A','B','C','D','E']
corner_pos = ['1','2','3','4']

def position_generator():
    #for centre, corner in zip(centre_pos, corner_pos):
    random_centre = random.choice(centre_pos)
    random_corner = random.choice(corner_pos)

    #if random_centre and random_corner in exclusion:

    #else:
    return random_centre, random_corner
```

However, I want to exclude certain combinations of centre_pos and corner_pos. For example if B and 1 occur in the same pseudorandomisation, then exclude this.
I want to exclude all these combinations:

```
exclusion = [('B', 1), ('C', 2), ('D', 3), ('E', 4)]
```

How do I get the 'exclusion' list to be excluded if any one of these positions occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the combinations with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), filter out the unwanted ones, then pick a random one with [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random
from itertools import product

def position_generator():
    
    centre_pos = ['A','B','C','D','E']
    corner_pos = ['1','2','3','4']
    
    exclusion = set([('B', '1'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '3'), ('E', '4')])
    
    return random.choice([x for x in product(centre_pos, corner_pos)
                          if x not in exclusion])

position_generator()
# ('B', '3')
```

If you plan to generate several coordinates, you might want to create a generator instead:

```
import random
from itertools import product

def position_generator():
    
    centre_pos = ['A','B','C','D','E']
    corner_pos = ['1','2','3','4']
    
    exclusion = set([('B', '1'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '3'), ('E', '4')])
    
    pos = [x for x in product(centre_pos, corner_pos) if x not in exclusion]
    random.shuffle(pos)
    
    return iter(pos)

gen = position_generator()

next(gen)
# ('E', '3')

next(gen)
# ('D', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the random generation in a loop such that it will loop until it generates a non excluded tuple.

```py
import random
centre_pos = ['A','B','C','D','E']
corner_pos = ['1','2','3','4']

def position_generator():
    exclusion = [('B', 1), ('C', 2), ('D', 3), ('E', 4)]
    while True:
        random_centre = random.choice(centre_pos)
        random_corner = random.choice(corner_pos)
        if (random_centre, random_corner) not in exclusion:
            return random_centre, random_corner
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to tackle this:

**Trying again on forbidden position**:
If you randomly generate a forbidden position, just start again:

```py
exclusion = [('B', 1), ('C', 2), ('D', 3), ('E', 4)]
def position_generator():
    #for centre, corner in zip(centre_pos, corner_pos):
    random_centre = random.choice(centre_pos)
    random_corner = random.choice(corner_pos)

    while (random_centre, random_corner) in exclusion:
        random_centre = random.choice(centre_pos)
        random_corner = random.choice(corner_pos)

    return random_centre, random_corner
```

But this means that you have to pre-compute the list of dis-allowed positions, and that the runtime of the function is unbounded, and could virtually be infinite (though that's **very** unlikely of course)

**Modify the list of possible choices, based on the random_centre**:
You can create a function to give you the possible corners, given the selected centre:

```py
def get_corners(centre):
    # Logic for which corners to include/exclude
    ...
```

and then, choose the corner amongst the valid answers only

```
random_corner = random.choice(get_corners(random_centre))
```

But note that this will modify the distribution on the output (it won't be uniform over the output tuples)

**Generate all possible tuples**:
Instead of drawing one variable at a time, generate the full space of possibilities you are interested in, and draw a tuple from there

```py
from itertools import product
exclusion = [('B', 1), ('C', 2), ('D', 3), ('E', 4)]
valid_positions = [x for x in product(centre_pos, corner_pos) if x not in exclusion]

def position_generator():
    return random.choice(valid_positions)
```